# How to use Azure Data Factory to copy files between Sharepoint 365 and OneDrive

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-data-factory

I have to build ADF pipelines that move files from Sharepoint document library folders into a single OneDrive which belongs to a 3rd party. I am unable to find good source of information on how to create Sharepoint and OneDrive datasets in ADF.

Any help on how to create the datasets would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please ref this document: [Azure Data Factory connector overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-overview)

They are not supported as the connector. We can not create the dataset.